# What are the 401(k) and IRA limits for next year?

Tags: united-states, ira, 401k, contribution, limits

Are 401(k) and IRA contribution limits increasing next year?  If so, what are the new limits?

Answer (score 9):

While a seemingly simple question, next year may be different.  Interestingly, the 2010 contribution limits for 401(k) and IRA plans is tied to the **rate of inflation**.   PF blogger [fivecentnickel.com](http://www.fivecentnickel.com/) posted the following article, [401(k) Limits to Decrease in 2010?](http://www.fivecentnickel.com/2009/08/27/401k-limits-to-decrease-in-2010/), which mentioned:

> Inflation has been **negative** since
>   March so, unless it picks up between
>   now and October, the IRS will have no
>   choice but to **reduce contribution
>   limits.** If this happens, the
>   contribution limits would fall from
>   $16,500 to $16,000 with catchup
>   contributions falling from $5,500 to
>   $5,000.

[Emphasis mine]

There's also a good article at [CNNMoney.com](http://CNNMoney.com), [New rule may mandate lower 401(k) contribution limits in 2010](http://moneyfeatures.blogs.money.cnn.com/2009/08/27/rule-may-mandate-lower-401k-contributions-in-2010/).  Check it out, too.

The final limits are supposed to be announced some time in October (i.e. later this month.)  I'll post a follow-up when I read about the announcement.

---

**UPDATE:**
The final 2010 401(k) contribution limits were announced by the IRS; see [this IRS press release](http://www.irs.gov/newsroom/article/0,,id=214321,00.html):

> IR-2009-94, Oct. 15, 2009 [...]
>
> The limitations that are adjusted by
>   reference to Section 415(d) will
>   remain unchanged for 2010.  This is
>   because the cost-of-living index for
>   the quarter ended September 30, 2009,
>   is less than the cost-of-living index
>   for the quarter ended September 30,
>   2008, and, following the procedures
>   under the Social Security Act for
>   adjusting benefit amounts, any decline
>   in the applicable index cannot result
>   in a reduced limitation.  For example,
>   the limitation under Section 402(g)(1)
>   on the exclusion for elective
>   deferrals described in Section
>   402(g)(3) will be $16,500 for 2010,
>   which is the same amount as for 2009.
>   [...]

**In other words, the 2010 employee contribution / deferral limit for a 401(k) plan is to be the same as in 2009: $16,500.**  If you are age 50 or over, additional catch-up contributions for a 401(k) plan remain limited to $5,500.

**For Individual Retirement Accounts, the contribution limit for 2010 is also to be the same as in 2009: $5,000.**  If you are age 50 or over, additional catch-up contributions for an IRA remain limited to $1,000.

Answer (score 6):

The IRS provides [excellent resources](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/Retirement-Topics-Contributions) regarding contribution limitations to [401(k)](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/Retirement-Topics---401%28k%29-and-Profit-Sharing-Plan-Contribution-Limits), [403(b)](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/Retirement-Topics---403%28b%29-Contribution-Limits), and [IRA](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/Retirement-Topics-IRA-Contribution-Limits) plans.

The basic limitations are as follows.

## 401(k) and 403(b) contribution limits (traditional and Roth combined)

- **2019** $19,000 ($25,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2018** $18,500 ($24,500 if age 50 or older)
- **2017** $18,000 ($24,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2016** $18,000 ($24,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2015** $18,000 ($24,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2014** $17,500 ($23,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2013** $17,500 ($23,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2012** $17,000 ($22,500 if age 50 or older)
- **2011** $16,500 ($22,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2010** $16,500 ($22,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2009** $16,500 ($22,000 if age 50 or older)

## IRA contribution limits (traditional and Roth combined)

- **2019** $6,000 ($7,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2018** $5,500 ($6,500 if age 50 or older)
- **2017** $5,500 ($6,500 if age 50 or older)
- **2016** $5,500 ($6,500 if age 50 or older)
- **2015** $5,500 ($6,500 if age 50 or older)
- **2014** $5,500 ($6,500 if age 50 or older)
- **2013** $5,500 ($6,500 if age 50 or older)
- **2012** $5,000 ($6,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2011** $5,000 ($6,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2010** $5,000 ($6,000 if age 50 or older)
- **2009** $5,000 ($6,000 if age 50 or older)

Comment: Nice history. Now you have to re-visit your answer each year and update with the latest numbers. Really.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - Ha, only if someone updates the question every year.

Comment: Touche! (This question was closed, and reopened on my request, figuring it would always have value if we would update each year. Nice to have company)

Comment: Six years later. Updated.

Comment: Unfortunately, despite the diligence over a long period, this doesn’t answer the question. Dare I downvote?

Comment: After 7 years, all but one of the links is broken :(